# How to create custom queries with spring data, hibernate, for mapped entities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

What I want is a query similar to :

```
SELECT s FROM First s WHERE s.x = :x and s.secondId.thirdId.id = :id;
```

I am trying to migrate this to spring data.
I can't figure out what should be the methodname in my repository.

My entities :

```
First{
    int x;
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Second secondId;
}

Second{
    int id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "third_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Third thirdId;
    int c;
}

Third {
    int id;
    // more data here
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

I tried : `findByThirdIdAndX(int id, xval);`
getting :

> Invalid derived query! No property thirdId found for type First

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thirdId` is a property of `secondId` that is a property of `First`. This is how you would specify that:

```
findBySecondIdThirdIdIdAndX(int id, int xval);
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) is the relevant doc for nested properties.

Comment: The variable name are SecondId and ThirdId so the method name should be : `findBySecondIdThirdIdIdAndX(int id, int xval)` or `findBySecondId_ThirdId_IdAndX(int id, int xval)`

Comment: thanks. it gets a bit complex writing method names for such queries. Not readable after a point. What should be the alternative? native queries?

Comment: @SachinSharma yes I've seen method names in spring data repositories with more than 120 chars. Using a `@Query` just for a shorter method name is a possibility in this case with pros and cons.